# Why does ADB over wifi take multiple attempts to connect?

Tags: adb, adbwireless

When connecting to my phone over WiFi using ADB I issue the command `adb connect <ip address>` however it typically takes 3 to 10 tries before the command works, why?

A typical session is show below, I'm changing nothing between when each command is run, yet eventually it magically works. Once it starts working, it continues to work.

I have port 5555 forwarded and wireless ADB enabled on my phone.

```
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
unable to connect to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
connected to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
192.168.0.8:5555    device
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb disconnect 192.168.0.8

gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
connected to 192.168.0.8:5555
gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb disconnect 192.168.0.8

gavin@gavin-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $ adb connect 192.168.0.8
connected to 192.168.0.8:5555
```

Comment: Did you try to ping your phone? Probably the wifi interface is sleeping.

Comment: Yep, it seems that was the issue. Thank you.